# How can I generate multiple PO files for Django Templates?

Tags: django, internationalization, django-i18n

I'd love to stay with Django's built-in localization tools if possible, but I'm afraid that won't be an option.

What I'd like to do is generate multiple different PO files for translation, based on my template files. E.g., instead of `/templates/home.html` and `/templates/other.html` dumping all of their strings into `django.po`, I'd like something like `home.po` and `other.po` -- or similar.

**Ideally**, a unique PO file for each template.

This would make asynchronous changes to multiple parts of the site *much* easier for us.

Is it possible to get that, or even similar behavior using the built in tools?

If not, how would you approach this?

Comment: I think it's not possible. But what you mean by "This would make asynchronous changes to multiple parts of the site much easier for us."?

Comment: Our current workflow and scheduling mean that some parts of the site are being actively translated by different teams, on different schedules. Templates may be added/removed before a translation team has turned in their work. This causes headaches when trying to keep track of and merge all the appropriate changes.

Comment: No luck with version control systems smart merging?